# dockeriser golem app: Error in loadNamespace

Tags: r, docker, golem

I want to dockerize a shiny application (named qrcodeapp) structured with the golem package. When i launch the command in deploy/README I get error with shiny version. It asks me for version 1.7.5 (what I indicate correctly in the description file shiny>=1.7.5) but it install version 1.7.4.

In the R console I executed this command `golem::add_dockerfile_with_renv(output_dir = "deploy")`
In the terminal I executed the commands (which are in the deploy/README file)

```
docker build -f Dockerfile_base --progress=plain -t qrcodeapp_base .
...
#11 135.5 # CRAN -----------------------------------------------------------------------
#11 135.5 - shiny         [repo: RSPM -> CRAN; ver: 1.7.4 -> 1.7.5]
...

docker build -f Dockerfile --progress=plain -t qrcodeapp:latest .
...
#9 7.016 Error in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]) :
#9 7.016   namespace ‘shiny’ 1.7.4 is being loaded, but >= 1.7.5 is required
#9 7.016 Calls: <Anonymous> ... withCallingHandlers -> loadNamespace -> namespaceImport -> loadNamespace
#9 7.016 Execution halted
...
```

DESCRIPTION

```
Imports: 
    config (>= 0.3.2),
    golem (>= 0.4.1),
    qrcode,
    shiny (>= 1.7.5),
    shinyjs
```

the complete log of the two commands: https://tangible-slug-162.notion.site/log-6c258b9521f84f9fb5f1efafabcd4fe4?pvs=4

Answer (score 0):

Any news on that problem?
I'm having the exact same issue (the only difference is that the req is 1.7.4.1, not 1.7.5).

Comment: Hello, i don't find a solution yet. I post a issue in the golem repo github: https://github.com/ThinkR-open/golem/issues/1112

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).